# Why is the compiler telling me that there is no definition for .Enabled?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm following Brackeys' tutorial on making a 3D game in Unity on Youtube and I'm up to the E05 (the collisions video) and I'm trying to make it so when you collide with the obstacle then the player movement is disabled. Here is the code:

Player Movement Code:

```
public Rigidbody rb;
public float forwardForce = 2000f;
public float sidewaysForce = 500f;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
    if(Input.GetKey("d"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("a"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Player Collision Code:

```
    public PlayerMovement movement;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
    {
        movement.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

However when I go back to Unity, the compiler tells me that PlayerMovement contains no definition for .Enabled. I'm sure I followed the video correctly, can anybody help?

Comment: Because it is lower case [`enabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html) maybe ...? As btw **all** built-in public properties in Unity. I am voting to close this question as **typo-based**

Comment: FYI C# is case sensitive, "Enabled" and "enabled" are different properties and only one exists

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't followed video corretly....
You must write enabled in lowercase, Enabled in upper case don't exit.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
    {
        movement.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)

Comment: I think that YES must answer, because an answer have more emphasis that a simple comment ant that simple the life for who can have identically issue and search a solution.